# how to run alias using bash -c from IDEA

Tags: bash, command-line

I'm trying to run a program defined in an alias (and the alias is defined in a source file)

```
alias myapp="/somepath/app -arg1 -arg2"
```

Then I go to IDEA and create an External Tool

```
Program: Bash
Arguments: -c "source /filewithalias.sh && myapp"
```

Then when I run, I get the following message:

```
bash: myapp: command not found
```

EDIT:

I already tried prepending

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

To the command string but the result is still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of your failure is that `myapp` is evaluated by `bash` at the time of the line evaluation, i.e. before its definition.
I suggest you to avoid aliases for this purpose (I can't find any easy method with aliases).

Here is a simple method.
If you don't have already one, create a personnal directory for all your
binaries and shell scripts:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
```

**Add** this new directory within your shell standard `PATH`:

```
PATH=${PATH}:~/bin
export PATH
```

Create a new shell script to fire your application with all the
required arguments:

```
$ cd ~/bin
$ cat >myapp.sh <<eof
/somepath/app -arg1 -arg2
eof
$ make myapp
```

check that it is working from your actual environment:

```
$ myapp
```

Then call it from IDEA:

```
Program: myapp
```

check that it is working from within IDEA.